# How bad is it to swap a hard-drive back and forth a few times?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd

I am currently running Fedora 19 on an SSD in my Lenovo x131e, and I am considering changing over to Mint (not dual booting).

I am in the middle of doing a PhD, so I have a lot of stuff on the drive with Fedora that I definitely don't want to lose, and if it turns out that I don't like Mint, I would like to be able to just continue on as i was with Fedora with minimum fuss (not have to reinstall all my old packages and transfer my data).

So my plan is this:

1. Buy a new SSD
2. Swap new SSD for old SSD
3. Install Mint on the new SSD
4. Use a SATA to USB converter to pull all my old data from the old drive
5. Use Mint for a while to see if i like it

   - if so, keep new set-up and use old SSD for something else
   - if not, swap old hard drive back in and use new SSD for something else

My question is, how bad is this for 1) my computer, or 2) the SSDs?

If it takes a while to get everything set up on the new drive, I might have to swap the drives a few times so that I can do work if i need to. But hopefully i should be able to get everything running over a weekend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard drives are designed to be replaceable and can be swapped multiple times without any concerns.  They are, however, intended to be handled by technicians and not necessarily end-users.  When changing the drives, observe the following:

- you probably already know that the system should be powered down and unplugged (in laptops the battery removed).  Give the system few minutes for internal capacitors to discharge.
- be gentle un-plugging and plugging the drives to prevent damaging the connectors
- observe ESD precautions

Comment: As Marcin said this will not damage your computer or drives if done correctly. ESD stands for Electro Static Discharge. To mitigate the risk to delicate electronics make sure you are grounded preferably with a wrist strap and optionally with all parts placed on a rubber work mat. Also keeping in contact with a piece of your metal case can sometimes be an additional precaution. At the very least remove your socks, try not to walk on carpet or wear layers, and discharge by touching the center screw of an outlet. Good luck!